# How can I insert variable in the HTML body?

Tags: html, ruby

I implemented the scripts that appending a child in the existing HTML body.
When I append a new child, I want to use variable in the value.

For example:

```
date=Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 

orig_html = defect.Field(@td_columns[:"Comments"])
  #XML module only provides html parsing without the DOCTYPE tag.
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(orig_html)    
tmp1 = '<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">#{date}</span></font></div>'
child1 = Nokogiri::XML::fragment(tmp1)
body = doc.at('body')
body.add_child(child1)
```

But, the `date` variable is not displayed as an actual date (ex. 2015-02-09) but just `#{date}`.

Does anyone have advice to insert variables in HTML contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a single-quote delimited string which doesn't allow interpolation of variables. Instead you have to use a double-quote delimited string or one of the forms that allows interpolation:

```
var_a = 'var_b'
'#{ var_a }'   # => "\#{ var_a }"
%q[#{ var_a }] # => "\#{ var_a }"
"#{ var_a }"   # => "var_b"
%[#{ var_a }]  # => "var_b"
%Q[#{ var_a }] # => "var_b"
```

Your code is too complicated. You can simplify it using:

```
tmp1 = "<div align='left'><font face='Arial'><span style='font-size:9pt'>#{date}</span></font></div>"
body = doc.at('body')
body.add_child(tmp1)
```

Nokogiri is smart enough to know it should convert the contents of `tmp1` into the equivalent HTML so you don't have to do it for it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

date = Time.now

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body></body></html>')
tmp1 = "<div align='left'><font face='Arial'><span style='font-size:9pt'>#{date}</span></font></div>"
body = doc.at('body')
body.add_child(tmp1)
puts body.to_html
# >> <body><div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:9pt">2015-02-08 23:30:49 -0700</span></font></div></body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contributions @the Tin Man

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation only works with double quotes:

```
foo = 'bar'
"foo #{foo} foo" # works and returns 'foo bar foo' 
'foo #{foo} foo' # does not work: 'foo #{foo} foo'
```

That said, change the quotes to double quotes (and escape existing double quotes) in the following line:

```
tmp1 = "<div align=\"left\"><font face=\"Arial\"><span style=\"font-size:9pt\">#{date}</span></font></div>"
```

Comment: instead of escaping double quotes you can use single quotes for attr values. Or use alternative string delimiters: `%{<div align="left">}`

Comment: Thanks for your contributions @Sergio Tulentsev